# Get automatically nodes and links from table for sankey diagram

Tags: r, sankey-diagram

For plotting a sankey diagram nodes and links are required. To get the nodes and links from a data frame one could use for example a count function from the package plyr and use it for each node to count the links between the neighbours but is there another elegant way?

example target, aim is to get nodes and links:

```
param1 | param2 | param3 |
a      | b      | d      |
w      | c      | d      |
a      | b      | d      |
z      | c      | e      |

#nodes:
nodes = data.frame("name" = 
c(
a, #node 0
w, #node 1
z, #node 2
b, #node 3
c, #node 4
d, #node 5
e  #node 6
))

#links
links = as.data.frame(matrix(c(
0, 3, 2, # from node 0,  to node 3, freq
1, 4, 1,
2, 4, 1,
3, 5, 2,
4, 5, 1,
4, 6, 1,
),
byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3))
```

Comment: Please provide example data. I am guessing *igraph* package would have a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *igraph* package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)

# example data
df1 <- read.table(text="
                  param1 param2 param3
                  a b d
                  w c d
                  a b d
                  z c e", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# make graph
g <- graph_from_data_frame(
  rbind(
    setNames(df1[, 1:2], c("from", "to")),
    setNames(df1[, 2:3], c("from", "to"))))


nodes <- data.frame(id = as.numeric(V(g)),
                    name = V(g)$name)
nodes
#   id name
# 1  1    a
# 2  2    w
# 3  3    z
# 4  4    b
# 5  5    c
# 6  6    d
# 7  7    e

links <- as.data.frame(get.edges(g, E(g))) %>%
  group_by(V1, V2) %>%
  summarise(freq = n()) %>% 
  data.frame()

links
#   V1 V2 freq
# 1  1  4    2
# 2  2  5    1
# 3  3  5    1
# 4  4  6    2
# 5  5  6    1
# 6  5  7    1
```

Comment: i have a further question, how can i avoid linking empty cells? would be great if you could help please

Comment: @hkn please avoid asking new questions in the comments, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).